# How to map an array of arrays into a JSX element in a react component, with each inner array having it's own clipPath

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, clip-path

array_groups is an array of arrays. The objects in the inner arrays are coordinates of regular circles, which are all proximal and the idea is that these inner arrays of circles should all be clipPath-ed together. The idea is that when I move my mouse over each area of proximal circles, the rect only shows in that area.

```
function Hoverpicture() {
 const [image, setimage] = useState("");
 const [mousepos, setmousepos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
 const [radius, setradius] = useState(20)
 const [label, setlabel] = useState("");
 const [region, setregion] = useState([]); 
 const [input, setinput] = useState("");
 const [mode, setmode] = useState(1);
 const [mousemove, setmousemove] = useState(()=>onmousemove);
 
  function onlabelclick(e) {
    setlabel("clicked label")
  }

  function onmouseclick(e) {
    let newregion = region.concat({ x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX, y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY, r: radius, label: input});
    setregion(newregion);
  }

  function checkregion(pos) {
    for (let reg of region) {
      let xs = pos.x - reg.x;
      let ys = pos.y - reg.y;
      xs*=xs;
      ys*=ys;
      console.log(reg);
      if (reg.r-Math.sqrt( xs + ys ) > 0) {
        return reg.label;
      } 
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  function onmousemove(e) {
    setmousepos({ x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX, y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY });
    let displaylabel = checkregion({x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX, y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY});
    if (displaylabel) {
      setlabel(displaylabel);
    } else {
      setlabel("");
    }
  }
  function handleinput(e) {
    setinput(e.target.value);
  }
  function myreducer(accum,next) {
              accum[next.label] = accum[next.label] || [];
              accum[next.label].push(next);
              return accum;
            }
  
  var grouped_region = region.reduce(function (accum,next) {
              accum[next.label] = accum[next.label] || [];
              accum[next.label].push(next);
              return accum;
            },{});

  
  var array_groups = [];
  for (let area in grouped_region) {
    array_groups.push(grouped_region[area]);
  }


  if (mode===1)
  {
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="img-overlay-wrap">
        <img src={image} alt="table with coffee"/>
        <svg onMouseMove={onmousemove} viewBox="0 0 auto auto">
          <circle cx={mousepos.x} cy={mousepos.y} r={radius} fill-opacity="0"/>
       
          {array_groups.map((ar,i) =>(
            <clipPath id="shape">
              {ar.map(reg =>(<circle onClick={onlabelclick} cx={reg.x} cy={reg.y} r={reg.r} fill="orange"/>))}
            </clipPath>
            <rect x={0} y={0} width="100%" height="100%" clipPath="url(#shape)" class="label"  fill-opacity="0"/>
            ))}
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>{ label }</h1>
        <button onClick={()=>{setmode(1)}}>✏</button>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    )}
```

The CSS looks like this..

```
.img-overlay-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* <= shrinks container to image size */
  transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.img-overlay-wrap img { /* <= optional, for responsiveness */
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.img-overlay-wrap svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.label:hover {
  fill-opacity:.5;
  fill:red;
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue? What are you asking for? Seems you've mapped the inner `ar` array.

Comment: Ah, well, the expected result would be that my onmousemove over the respective clipped regions would fill in red, but that doesn't happen. I've had success getting all the regions to fill in red on an onmousemove, in an earlier attempt..in that attempt I only had one map, and the original structure was just an array of objects, not an array of arrays of objects.. It seems I can't get the nested maps to work properly with the respective clipPaths..It always complains about "adjacent JSX elements" needing parents..but anywhere I put some <div> wrappers, there is no functionality

Comment: That's a new warning/error to me, care to update your question with a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example (so we can see the handler, etc..) and that warning/error message?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mchielouis/pen/gOwXrpY?editors=0010 This is my codepen, if you care to look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, yeah, I *have* seen that one. You just need to enclose all those adjacent tags (`clipPath` and `rect`) in a single node for the mapping return. React `Fragment` comes in handy for this.

[Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) - [keyed Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments)

> Fragments declared with the explicit `<React.Fragment>` syntax may have
> keys. A use case for this is mapping a collection to an array of
> fragments

```
{array_groups.map((ar, i) => (
  <Fragment key={i}>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      {ar.map((reg) => (
        <circle
          onClick={onlabelclick}
          cx={reg.x}
          cy={reg.y}
          r={reg.r}
          fill="orange"
        />
      ))}
    </clipPath>
    <rect
      x={0}
      y={0}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      clipPath="url(#shape)"
      class="label"
      fill-opacity="0"
    />
  </Fragment>
))}
```

I can't save the edits I made to your codepen, but I can copy the contents of the component here.

```
function Hoverpicture() {
  const [image, setimage] = useState("");
  const [mousepos, setmousepos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [radius, setradius] = useState(20);
  const [label, setlabel] = useState("");
  const [region, setregion] = useState([]);
  const [input, setinput] = useState("");
  const [mode, setmode] = useState(1);

  function getimage() {
    storage
      .child("peterRabbit.png")
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        let image = url;
        setimage(image);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors
      });
  }

  function getlabels() {
    let doc = ref.doc("01xfB3duoKI2Uoq4gtYZ");
    doc.get().then((d) => {
      console.log(d.data());
    });
  }
  getlabels();
  getimage();
  function onlabelclick(e) {
    setlabel("clicked label");
  }
  function onmouseclick(e) {
    let newregion = region.concat({
      x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX,
      y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY,
      r: radius,
      label: input
    });
    setregion(newregion);
  }
  function getcoords() {}
  function checkregion(pos) {
    for (let reg of region) {
      let xs = pos.x - reg.x;
      let ys = pos.y - reg.y;
      xs *= xs;
      ys *= ys;
      console.log(reg);
      if (reg.r - Math.sqrt(xs + ys) > 0) {
        return reg.label;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function onmousemove(e) {
    setmousepos({ x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX, y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY });
    let displaylabel = checkregion({
      x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX,
      y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY
    });
    if (displaylabel) {
      setlabel(displaylabel);
    } else {
      setlabel("");
    }
  }
  function handleinput(e) {
    setinput(e.target.value);
  }
  function myreducer(accum, next) {
    accum[next.label] = accum[next.label] || [];
    accum[next.label].push(next);
    return accum;
  }
  const [mousemove, setmousemove] = useState(() => onmousemove);
  var grouped_region = region.reduce(function (accum, next) {
    accum[next.label] = accum[next.label] || [];
    accum[next.label].push(next);
    return accum;
  }, {});
  console.log(grouped_region);
  var array_groups = [];
  for (let area in grouped_region) {
    array_groups.push(grouped_region[area]);
  }
  
  if (mode === 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="img-overlay-wrap">
          <img src={image} alt="table with coffee" />
          <svg onMouseMove={onmousemove} viewBox="0 0 auto auto">
            <circle
              cx={mousepos.x}
              cy={mousepos.y}
              r={radius}
              fill-opacity="0"
            />

            {array_groups.map((ar, i) => (
              <>
                <clipPath id="shape">
                  {ar.map((reg) => (
                    <circle
                      onClick={onlabelclick}
                      cx={reg.x}
                      cy={reg.y}
                      r={reg.r}
                      fill="orange"
                    />
                  ))}
                </clipPath>
                <rect
                  x={0}
                  y={0}
                  width="100%"
                  height="100%"
                  clipPath="url(#shape)"
                  class="label"
                  fill-opacity="0"
                />
              </>
            ))}
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>{label}</h1>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setmode(1);
            }}
          >
            ✏
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (mode === 1) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="img-overlay-wrap">
          <img src={image} alt="table with coffee" />
          <svg
            onMouseMove={onmousemove}
            onClick={onmouseclick}
            viewBox="0 0 auto auto"
          >
            <circle
              cx={mousepos.x}
              cy={mousepos.y}
              r={radius}
              fill="rebeccapurple"
            />
            {region.map((reg) => (
              <circle
                onClick={onlabelclick}
                class="label"
                cx={reg.x}
                cy={reg.y}
                r={reg.r}
                fill="orange"
              />
            ))}
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>
            {mousepos.x} {mousepos.y}
          </h1>
          <h1>{label}</h1>
          <input
            placeholder="label"
            value={input}
            onChange={handleinput}
          ></input>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setmode(0);
            }}
          >
            ✅
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah it works! Well, I can't claim to understand about why these fragment tags are necessary..but, now that I changed the clippath id to include the array position id, ie id=`{"shape+i"}` and correspondingly in the rect, it works perfectly. Thank you also for the implicit formatting/indenting suggestions, looks so much more readable

Comment: @user3743847 All react children ***must*** be returned in a single node, the `Fragment` allows you to do this without dirtying the DOM. As for the formatting, I literally copied into codesandbox, hit format, copy/paste here. If you're not familiar, codesandbox is basically a web version of VScode, it's great for quick prototyping, making minimal examples, and quick formats. Cheers.

Comment: Why is there a special syntax for this (isn't the DOM is restructuring the nodes in the tree under the hood pretty often anyways)? Is it because of the React component "paradigm"? Ie, should I be making an intermediary component? Like, maybe I should make a clipPathAndRectForCombinedCircleRegions component..haha now that's a name.. where it'll have props.RegionCoords and props.clipPathID just for mapping, clipping and filling the <circles>...What happens then is I just map those directly in the svg using the outer array indices..hmm

Comment: @user3743847 It's a React thing. React maintains a virtual DOM that is then rendered to the DOM. Sure, you can abstract the "Fragment" and children into a component, but the component would still need to return a single Node.